# While loop based on if statements looping but not checking

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

Im trying to make a way for the user to check all of their individual stats when asking for them, and this is how I'm doing it. The problem is, when I run it, I can use **one** of the if functions **or** the while condition (making the program end), but after that I have no clue what happens. It obviously keeps looping but the program doesn't end and I can't use the other if functions, any thoughts?

```
print("ask about your stats")
userInput = input()
while userInput != "Pass":
    if userInput == "Stats":
        print(billyMays)
    elif userInput == "Health":
        print(health)
    elif userInput == "Hunger":
        print(hunger)
    elif userInput == "Voice":
        print(voice)
    else:
        pass
    userInput = None
print("goodbye")
```

Comment: Instead of setting `userInput = None`, try `userInput = input()`.

Comment: You set `userInput = None` at the end of the first iteration. How do you think that's going to affect all those `userInput != "Pass"` and `userInput == "Stats"` and similar checks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you assign `userInput = None`, the while condition remains `True` forever and the body of the loop effectively does nothing.